# How to put glyphicon in bootstrap form?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap form and want to add a glyphicon before the SELECT fields.
However, it makes a breakline somewhy.

```
<form role="form" id="registration-form" onsubmit="return onSubmitContinueButton()">

    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">           
            <label class="sr-only" for="xxx"></label>   
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-name"></span> <!--  <-- there is a breakline after this.... why?-->            
            <select class="form-control" name="aaa">                
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>                
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">           
            <label class="sr-only" for="xxx"></label>           
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-name"></span> <!--  <-- there is a breakline after this.... why?-->            
            <select class="form-control" name="aaa">                
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>                
            </select>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</form>
```

I want the glyphicon to be just near the select field and not above it.
How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add icons in front of the select field make it an input group like this

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span>
   <select class="form-control" name="aaa">                
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>                
        </select>
</div>
```

For more information look right here: [Bootstrap input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)

Comment: Thanks, it puts the icon near the select, however, all the select inputs are now one below the other. I want them to be  horizontally lined. How can that be done?

Comment: This also can be found on the http://getbootstrap.com/ website [right here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline). Please check the documentation more carefully before asking questions.